# Moving multiple queries from access to sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

First off, I am terrible at Access and pretty bad at anything that is not .Net (As you can see, I keep trying to write in .Net)

What I am trying to do is to take each query that is in an Access DB and to save it on a Sharepoint list.

something like:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function SendUpdate()
     Dim DB as Access.Db = C:\Test.accdb

     For Each Qry as Query in DB
           DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "WSS", DB, _
           "http://My.sharepointlist.com/list", _
           acQuery, Qry, Qry, True, Login, Password
     Loop
End Function
```

Obviously the `For Each` part doesn't work, but even when I do:

DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, `WSS`, DB, `http://My.sharepointlist.com/list`,         acQuery, Qry, Qry, True, Login, Password

By itself I am getting a run-time error `3841` and I was hoping at least that part worked. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks for the help,
Zach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you want looks like this:

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, _
                   "WSS", _
                   "http://YourTargetDatabase/TestSubSite", _
                   acQuery, _
                   "q2", _
                   "q2"
```

A break down of this is:

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, _
         "WSS", _     (Type of export – WSS)
         "http://YourTargetDatabase"    (target database location), _
         acQuery, _             (type of export)
         "q2",                       (name of query to export)
         "q2"                         (name to create on target system)
```

The "store" password option you have is NOT a connection string nor is it a password. It is only a true/false setting for the password to be stored – and I don't think this applies to SharePoint but only certain types of odbc connections.

So, if you are currently logged into the SharePoint site, then the above will run without password prompts. If you not logged in, then you will receive a logon prompt, and then the above should work just fine.

If you going to code this as a for/each as you have, then the syntax would be like this:

```
Sub TransferQuery()

  Dim qryDef     As DAO.QueryDef

  For Each qryDef In CurrentDb.QueryDefs

     DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, _
                   "WSS", _
                   "http://YourTargetDatabase/TestSubSite", _
                   acQuery, _
                   qryDef.Name, _
                   qryDef.Name

  Next


End Sub
```